# A Challenging Logarithmic Integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)\log(1-x)\log^2(1+x)}{x}dx$

Tags: analysis, integration, special-functions, definite-integrals

How can we prove that:

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)\log(1-x)\log^2(1+x)}{x}dx=\frac{7\pi^2}{48}\zeta(3)-\frac{25}{16}\zeta(5)$$ where $\zeta(z)$ is the [*Riemann Zeta Function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

The best I could do was to express it in terms of Euler Sums. Let $I$ denote the integral.

$$I=-\frac{\pi^2}{24}\zeta(3)+2\sum_{r=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^r (H_r)^2}{r^3}-2\sum_{r=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^r H_r}{r^4}+2 \sum_{r=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^r H_r^{(2)}H_r}{r^2}-2\sum_{r=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^r H_r^{(2)}}{r^3}$$

where $\displaystyle H_r^{(n)}=\sum_{n=1}^r \frac{1}{k^n}$. I am unable to simplify these sums further. Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this integral?

Please see [here](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic186.html) for more details.

---

Some time ago I was able to solve the simpler integral:

> \begin{align*} \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x)\log(x)\log(1+x)}{x}dx &=-\frac{3 \pi^4}{160}+\frac{7\log(2)}{4}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2 \log^2(2)}{12} +\frac{\log^4(2)}{12} \\ &\quad+ 2 \text{Li}_4 \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) \end{align*} where $\text{Li}_n(z)$ is the [Polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Let the considered integral be denoted by $I$. Our starting point is to reduce the number of logarithms of different arguments in the integrand. Thus, using the fact
that $6ab^2=(a+b)^3-2a^3+(a-b)^3$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
6I&=\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{x}\log^3(1-x^2)dx}_{x\leftarrow \sqrt{u}}
-2\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{x}\log^3(1-x)dx+
\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{x}\log^3\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)dx}_{x\leftarrow\frac{1-u}{1+u}}
 \\
&= \frac{1}{4}\int_0^1\frac{\log u}{u}\log^3(1-u)du
-2\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{x}\log^3(1-x)dx+
2\int_0^1\frac{\log^3 u}{1-u^2}\log\left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right)du \\
&=\frac{-7}{4}\int_0^1\frac{\log x}{x}\log^3(1-x)dx+
2\int_0^1\frac{\log^3 x}{1-x^2}\log\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)dx \\
\end{align*}
Thus,
$$
I=-\frac{7}{24}J+\frac{1}{3}K \tag{1}
$$
with
$$
J=\int_0^1\frac{\log(1- x)}{1-x}\log^3x\,dx,\quad
K=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-x^2}\log\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\log^3 x\,dx
\tag{2}
$$
Now, for $x\in(-1,1)$, we have
$$
\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x}=-\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}\right)
=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_nx^n
$$
where $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n1/k$ is the $n$-th Harmonic number. Similarly,
$$
\frac{1}{1-x^2}\log\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)
=-\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{2k}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{-2x^{2k-1}}{2k-1}\right)
=-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \widetilde{H}_nx^{2n-1}
$$
where
$$\widetilde{H}_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k-1}
=H_{2n}-\frac{1}{2}H_n$$
Thus, using the fact that $\int_0^1x^n(-\log x)^3\,dx=-6/(n+1)^4$ we conclude that
\begin{align*} 
J&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n\int_0^1x^n(-\log x)^3\,dx=6\sum_{n=1}^\infty
\frac{H_n}{(n+1)^4}\\
&=6\sum_{n=0}^\infty
\frac{1}{(n+1)^4}\left(H_{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=6A-6\zeta(5)\tag{3}
\end{align*}
with
\begin{equation*} 
A=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}\tag{4}
\end{equation*}
Similarly,
\begin{align*} 
K&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2H_{2n}-H_n)\int_0^1x^{2n-1}(-\log x)^3\,dx=6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2H_{2n}-H_n}{(2n)^4}\\
&=6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1+(-1)^{2n})H_{2n}}{(2n)^4}
-\frac{3}{8}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}\\
&=6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1+(-1)^{n})H_{n}}{n^4}
-\frac{3}{8}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}\\
&=\frac{45}{8}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}}{n^4}
+6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}H_{n}}{n^4}=\frac{45}{8}A+6B\tag{5}
\end{align*}
with
\begin{equation*} 
B=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^4}\tag{6}
\end{equation*}
Combining (1) with (3) and (5) we find that
\begin{equation*} 
I=\frac{1}{8}A+2B+\frac{7}{4}\zeta(5)\tag{7}
\end{equation*}
Now, sums $A$ and $B$ are known (see [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X87900126) ) (in a more general setting), and
we have
$$
A=3\zeta(5)-\zeta(2)\zeta(3),\qquad
B=-\frac{59}{32}\zeta(5)+\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)
$$
Thus
$$
I=\frac{7}{8}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{25}{16}\zeta(5).
$$
which is the announced result.$\qquad\square$

Answer (score 5):

On the path of Omran Kouba,

\begin{align}
K_1&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(x)\ln(1-x)}{1-x}dx\\
K_2&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(x)\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx\\
U&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(x)\ln(1+x)}{1-x}dx\\
V&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(x)\ln(1-x)}{1+x}dx\\
Z&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\ln^3 x}{1-x^2}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\ln^3 x}{1-x}dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\ln^3 x}{1+x}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}K_1-\frac{1}{2}U+\frac{1}{2}V-\frac{1}{2}K_2\\
J&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x)\ln(1-x)\ln^2(1+x)}{x}dx&=\\
J&=-\frac{7}{24}K_1+\frac{1}{3}Z\\
&=-\frac{7}{24}K_1+\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}K_1-\frac{1}{2}U+\frac{1}{2}V-\frac{1}{2}K_2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}V-\frac{1}{6}U-\frac{1}{8}K_1-\frac{1}{6}K_2
\end{align}
From [Integrating $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^3 x}{1+x}\,dx$ with restricted techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3762687/integrating-int-01-frac-ln1x-ln3-x1x-dx-with-restricted-technique)

One obtains,
\begin{align*}K_1&=12\zeta(5)-6\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\
K_2&=\frac{1}{2}K_1-\frac{9}{16}\zeta(5)\\
U&=-\frac{45}{4}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+12\zeta(5)\\
V&=\frac{273}{16}\zeta(5)-\frac{45}{4}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\
\end{align*}

Therefore,

\begin{align*}J&=\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{273}{16}\zeta(5)-\frac{45}{4}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\right)-\frac{1}{6}\left(-\frac{45}{4}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+12\zeta(5)\right)-\\
&\frac{1}{8}\Big(12\zeta(5)-6\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\Big)-\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{87}{16}\zeta(5)-3\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\right)\\
&=\frac{7}{8}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{25}{16}\zeta(5)\\
&=\boxed{\frac{7}{48}\pi^2\zeta(3)-\frac{25}{16}\zeta(5)}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I simplified my solution. My original solution was about 3 times longer than this, so it is so lucky for me to find a shortcut like this :)

Step 1. Let $I$ be the integral in question:
\begin{align*}
I &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log x \log (1 - x) \log^{2} (1 + x)}{x} \, dx.
\end{align*} By the simple algebraic formula  $(a + b)^{3} + (a - b)^{3} - 2 a^{3} = 6 a b^{2}$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
I
&= \frac{1}{6} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log x}{x} \left\{ \log^{3} (1-x^{2}) + \log^{3} \left( \frac{1-x}{1+x} \right) - 2\log^{3}(1-x) \right\} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{6} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log x \log^{3} (1-x^{2})}{x} \, dx + \frac{1}{6} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log x \log^{3} \left( \frac{1-x}{1+x} \right)}{x} \, dx - \frac{1}{3} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log x \log^{3} (1-x)}{x} \, dx \tag{1}
\end{align*} Applying the substitution $x^{2} \mapsto x$, the first integral reduces to
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{6} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log x \log^{3} (1-x^{2})}{x} \, dx
&= \frac{1}{24} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log x \log^{3} (1-x)}{x} \, dx
= \frac{1}{24} \frac{\partial^{4}\beta}{\partial z \partial w^{3}}(0^{+}, 1) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\zeta(5) - \frac{1}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3).
\end{align*} So $\text{(1)}$ can be written as
\begin{align*}
I &= \frac{7}{4} \zeta(2)\zeta(3) - \frac{7}{2} \zeta(5) + I_{2}, \tag{2}
\end{align*} where ( I_{2} ) is given by
\begin{align*}
I_{2} = \frac{1}{6} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log x \log^{3} \left( \frac{1-x}{1+x} \right)}{x} \, dx
\end{align*}

Step 2. Now we calculate $I_{2}$. Applying integrating by parts, followed by the substitution $x \mapsto \displaystyle \frac{1-y}{1+y}$, we have
\begin{align*}
I_{2} &= \left[ \frac{1}{12} \log^{2} x \log^{3} \left( \frac{1-x}{1+x} \right) \right]_{0}^{1} + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log^{2} x \log^{2} \left( \frac{1-x}{1+x} \right)}{1 - x^{2}} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log^{2} y \log^{2} \left( \frac{1-y}{1+y} \right)}{y} \, dy \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log^{2} y}{y} \left\{ \frac{1}{2} \log^{2} \left( \frac{1+y}{1-y} \right) \right\}^{2} \, dy \\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2m+1)(2n+1)} \int_{0}^{1} y^{2m+2n+1} \log^{2} y \, dy \\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(2m+1)(2n+1)(2m+2n+2)^{3}}.
\end{align*} By the following partial fraction decomposition
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{ab(a+b)^{3}} = \frac{a+b}{a b(a+b)^{4}} = \frac{1}{a(a+b)^{4}} + \frac{1}{b(a+b)^{4}},
\end{align*}
together with the symmetry in the role of $m$ and $n$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
I_{2}
&= 4 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2m+2n+2)^{4}}
= \frac{1}{4} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)(m+n+1)^{4}} \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n+1} \cdot \frac{1}{m^{4}}
= \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n-1} \cdot \frac{1}{m^{4}} \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{1}{2n-1} \right) \frac{1}{m^{4}}.
\end{align*} Now by exploiting the following identity
\begin{align*}
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - x^{k}}{1 - x} \, dx = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{k} \\
\Longrightarrow & \quad
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 + x^{k} - 2x^{2k}}{2(1 - x)} \, dx = 1 + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2k-1},
\end{align*} we can rephrase $I_{2}$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
I_{2}
&= \frac{1}{8} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^{4}} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 + x^{m} - 2x^{2m}}{1 - x} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{8} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1-x} \left( \zeta(4) + \mathrm{Li}_{4}(x) - 2 \mathrm{Li}_{4}(x^{2}) \right) \, dx.
\end{align*} Writing ( \displaystyle \frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{\mathrm{Li}*{0}(x)}{x} ) and applying the simple differentiation rule $$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \mathrm{Li}_{s} (x^{p}) = \frac{p \mathrm{Li}_{s-1}(x^{p})}{x}$$, by applying integrating parts 3 times,
\begin{align*}
I_{2}
&= \frac{1}{8} \left[ \mathrm{Li}_{1}(x) \left( \zeta(4) + \mathrm{Li}_{4}(x) - 2 \mathrm{Li}_{4}(x^{2}) \right) \right]_{0}^{1} - \frac{1}{8} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{Li}_{1}(x)}{x} \left( \mathrm{Li}_{3}(x) - 4 \mathrm{Li}_{3}(x^{2}) \right) \, dx \\
&= -\frac{1}{8} \left[ \mathrm{Li}_{2}(x) \left( \mathrm{Li}_{3}(x) - 4 \mathrm{Li}_{3}(x^{2}) \right) \right]_{0}^{1} + \frac{1}{8} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{Li}_{2}(x)}{x} \left( \mathrm{Li}_{2}(x) - 8 \mathrm{Li}_{2}(x^{2}) \right) \, dx \\
&= \frac{3}{8} \zeta(2)\zeta(3) + \frac{1}{8} \left[ \mathrm{Li}_{3}(x) \left( \mathrm{Li}_{2}(x) - 8 \mathrm{Li}_{2}(x^{2}) \right) \right]_{0}^{1} - \frac{1}{8} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{Li}_{3}(x)}{x} \left( \mathrm{Li}_{1}(x) - 16 \mathrm{Li}_{1}(x^{2}) \right) \, dx \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3) + \frac{1}{8} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{Li}_{3}(x)}{x} \left( \log(1 - x) - 16 \log(1 - x^{2}) \right) \, dx \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3) + \frac{1}{8} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{Li}_{3}(x) \log(1 - x)}{x} \, dx - 2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{Li}_{3}(x) \log(1 - x^{2}) }{x}\, dx.
\end{align*} Now applying the substitution  $x \mapsto x^{2}$ to the first integral, from the identity  $\mathrm{Li}_{3}(x^{2}) = 4 \mathrm{Li}_{3}(x) + 4 \mathrm{Li}_{3}(-x)$ it follows that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{8} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{Li}_{3}(x) \log(1 - x)}{x} \, dx
&= \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{Li}_{3}(x^{2}) \log(1 - x^{2})}{x} \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{ \{ \mathrm{Li}_{3}(x) + \mathrm{Li}_{3}(-x) \} \log(1 - x^{2})}{x} \, dx.
\end{align*} This finally gives
\begin{align*}
I_{2} = -\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3) - \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{Li}_{3}(x) \log(1 - x^{2}) }{x}\, dx.
\end{align*} Plugging this back to ( \text{(2)} ), we obtain
\begin{align*}
I_{1} = \frac{5}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3) - \frac{7}{2}\zeta(5) + I_{3}, \tag{3}
\end{align*} where ( I*{3} ) is given by
\begin{align*}
I_{3} = - \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{Li}_{3}(x) \log(1 - x^{2})}{x} \, dx.
\end{align*}

Step 3. Finally, we evaluate $I_{3}$ into a closed form and thus complete the calculation. Since the integrand is holomorphic on the unit disc, we can shift up the contour of integration to the clockwise semicircular arc:
\begin{align*}
I_{3}
&= -i \int_{\pi}^{0} \mathrm{Li}_{3}(e^{i\theta}) \log(1 - e^{2i\theta}) \, d\theta
= - \frac{1}{i} \int_{0}^{\pi} \mathrm{Li}_{3}(e^{i\theta}) \log(1 - e^{2i\theta}) \, d\theta
\end{align*} Now expanding with Taylor series and taking advantage of the fact that $I_{3}$ is real, we have
\begin{align*}
I_{3}
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}} \frac{1}{m} \int_{0}^{\pi} \{ \cos (n\theta) \sin (2m\theta) + \sin(n\theta) \cos(2m\theta) \} \, d\theta \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}} \frac{1}{m} \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos (n\theta) \sin (2m\theta) \, d\theta \\
&\qquad + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}} \frac{1}{m} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(n\theta) \cos(2m\theta) \, d\theta \\
&=: S_{1} + S_{2}.
\end{align*} To evaluate $S_{1}$, we note the following simple identity
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos (n\theta) \sin (2m\theta) \, d\theta
= \frac{1 + (-1)^{n-1}}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos (\tfrac{1}{2} n\theta) \sin (m\theta) \, d\theta.
\end{align*} Then we can write
\begin{align*}
S_{1} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{3}} \int_{0}^{\pi} \left\{ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (m\theta)}{m} \right\} \cos((n+\tfrac{1}{2})\theta) \, d\theta, \\
S_{2} &= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m} \int_{0}^{\pi} \left\{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n^{3}} \right\} \cos(2m\theta) \, d\theta.
\end{align*} But it is not hard to check that the following Fourier expansion holds:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n\theta}{n} = \Im \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i\theta}}{n} = - \Im \log(1 - e^{i\theta}) = \frac{\pi-\theta}{2}, \quad 0 < \theta < \pi,
\end{align*} \begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n\theta}{n^{3}} = \frac{\theta ^3}{12}-\frac{\pi \theta ^2}{4}+\frac{\pi ^2 \theta }{6}, \quad 0 < \theta < \pi.
\end{align*} Plugging these to $S_{1}$, $S_{2}$ and performing some tedious calculation, we obtain
\begin{align*}
S_{1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(2n+1)^{5}} = \frac{31}{16} \zeta(5)
\quad \text{and} \quad
S_{2} = -\frac{\pi^{2}}{16} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^{3}} = -\frac{3}{8}\zeta(2)\zeta(3).
\end{align*} Therefore we have
\begin{align*}
I = \frac{7}{8}\zeta(2)\zeta(3) - \frac{25}{16} \zeta(5).
\end{align*}