# How to calculate $\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}\ dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, harmonic-numbers, beta-function

Using the derivative of beta function, find

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}\ dx$$

setting $x^2=y$ gives

$$I=\frac18\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2y\ln^2(1-y)}{\sqrt{y}(1-y)}\ dy=\frac18\left.\frac{\partial^4}{\partial a^2\partial b^2}\text{B}(a,b)\right|_{a\mapsto 1/2\\b\mapsto0^{+}}$$

Any good software that can find the 4th derivative and also gives the final result? Wolfram fails to calculate it (or maybe I do not know how to use it well) and when I tried to do it manually, some terms involve $\psi(b)$ and if we take the limit, then $\psi(0)$ is undefined and even if I take the limit of $\psi(b)$ together with other terms, still undefined. I do not know how to avoid this problem as I am not experienced with the beta function.

Thank you.

---

**Note:** Solution should be done without using harmonic series.

Comment: Mathematica returns this as $$I=-\frac{7 \pi ^2 \zeta (3)}{3}+31 \zeta (5)+\frac{7}{4} \zeta (3) \log ^2(4)-\frac{1}{8}
   \pi ^4 \log (2).$$

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1949150/515527) might be helpful, look at $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: @YiFan thank you thats very helpful.

Comment: @カカロット Thank you its an interesting solution.

Comment: @YiFan would you mind trying $\lim_{b\mapsto 0^{+}}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial b^2}\text{B}(a,b)$ please? If mathematica gives a closed form, then the rest will be pretty easy..

Comment: @AliShather If my code is correct, Mathematica returns $+\infty$.

Comment: @YiFan thank you so much.. that means even mathematica can not do it. has be done manually just like M.N.C.E did here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096557/calculate-int-01-frac-log21x-logx-log1-x1-xdx/1949150#1949150

Comment: Gamma and polygamma functions are the most developed special functions in *Mathematica*, you can literally get anything you want (e.g. limit, derivative, simplifications, evaluation at special arguments). 

If one cannot find the limit as simple as that posed in the question, it's the user's mathematical manipulation needs improvement rather than the CAS. Wolfram|Alpha is, of course, less powerful than *Mathematica*.

Comment: @pisco thank you for all these commands... very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the following *Mathematica* commands calculate your limit, in decreasing order of time (the more naive one uses more time):

```
Limit[D[Gamma[a]*Gamma[b]/Gamma[a + b], {a, 2}, {b, 2}] /. {a -> 
  1/2 + x, b -> x}, x -> 0] // FunctionExpand // Expand
```

the above command directly calculates the limit, by choosing a path approaching $(a,b)=(1/2,0)$. It takes $32$ seconds on my machine.

```
D[Normal[Series[
        Gamma[a]*Gamma[b]/Gamma[a + b], {a, 1/2, 4}, {b, 0, 4}]], {a, 
       2}, {b, 2}] /. a -> 1/2 /. b -> 0 // FullSimplify // 
  Expand
```

rather than calculating the limit, this one uses series expansion up to constant term. It takes $12$ seconds.

```
Normal[Series[
     D[Gamma[a]*Gamma[b]/Gamma[a + b], {a, 2}, {b, 2}], {a, 1/2, 
      0}, {b, 0, 0}]] // FullSimplify // Expand
```

this one does not even calculate derivatives, instead uses series expansion up to 4th order. It takes $3.5$ seconds.

```
D[Exp[Series[
        LogGamma[a] + LogGamma[b] - LogGamma[a + b], {a, 1/2, 4}, {b, 
         0, 4}]], {a, 2}, {b, 2}] /. a -> 1/2 /. b -> 0 // 
   FullSimplify // Expand
```

This use the well-known simple series of log gamma function, it takes only $0.5$ seconds.

---

It's easy to guess why the fourth one is most efficient. To see how much is used for each computation, execute `ClearSystemCache[];(your command)//Timing`.

Such beta limit arising from logarithm integrals is well-known, it's also not difficult to write down an recursion for it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried all these commands I know how to calculate limits on mathematica now I really need it. To be honest, the first one is my fav as its easy to remember. Thanks again @pisco .

Answer (score 2):

**A magnificent solution by Cornel without using the derivative of beta function.**

---

We have [the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366039/a-group-of-important-generating-functions-involving-harmonic-number)

$$\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (H_n^2-H_n^{(2)})x^n$$

replace $x$ with $x^2$, then multiply both sides by $\ln^2x$ and integrate from $x=0$ to $1$ we get

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}\ dx=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}}{(2n+1)^3}\tag1$$

---

By [the master theorem](http://files.ele-math.com/articles/jca-10-10.pdf), we have

$$3n\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H_k^2-H_k^{(2)}}{(k+1)(k+n+1)}=H_n^3+3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}$$

differentiate both sides with respect to $n$ to get

$$3\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H_k^2-H_k^{(2)}}{(k+n+1)^2}=\frac{d}{dn}\left(H_n^3+3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}\right)$$

differentiate again and let $n\mapsto -1/2$ we get

$$-6\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H_k^2-H_k^{(2)}}{(k+1/2)^3}=\frac{d^2}{dn^2}\left(H_n^3+3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}\right)_{n\mapsto-1/2}$$

or

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H_k^2-H_k^{(2)}}{(2k+1)^3}=\frac{31}{2}\zeta(5)-\frac{45}{8}\ln2\zeta(4)+\frac72\ln^22\zeta(3)-7\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\tag2$$

---

From (1) and (2) we get

> $$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}\ dx=31\zeta(5)-\frac{45}{4}\ln2\zeta(4)+7\ln^22\zeta(3)-14\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
I & \equiv
{1 \over 8}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{y}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - y} \over \root{y}\pars{1 - y}}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
\left.{1 \over 8}{\partial^{2} \over
\partial \mu^{2}\,\partial \nu^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}
\pars{y^{\,\mu - 1/2} - 1}\pars{1 - y}^{\,\nu - 1} \,\dd y\,
\right\vert_{\ {\Large\mu\ =\ 0} \atop {\Large\nu\ =\ 0}}
\\[5mm] & =
\left.{1 \over 8}{\partial^{4} \over
\partial \mu^{2}\,\partial \nu^{2}}\bracks{{\Gamma\pars{\mu +1/2}
\Gamma\pars{\nu} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + \nu + 1/2}} -
{1 \over \nu}}\,
\right\vert_{\ {\Large\mu\ =\ 0} \atop {\Large\nu\ =\ 0}}
\\[5mm] & =
\left.{1 \over 8}{\partial^{4} \over
\partial \mu^{2}\,\partial \nu^{2}}\braces{{1 \over \nu}\bracks{{\Gamma\pars{\mu +1/2}
\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + \nu + 1/2}} - 1}}\,
\right\vert_{\ {\Large\mu\ =\ 0} \atop {\Large\nu\ =\ 0}}
\\[5mm] & =
\left.{1 \over 24}{\partial^{5} \over
\partial \mu^{2}\,\partial \nu^{3}}{\Gamma\pars{\mu +1/2}
\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + \nu + 1/2}}\,
\right\vert_{\ {\Large\mu\ =\ 0} \atop {\Large\nu\ =\ 0}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{-\,{7 \pi ^2 \over 3}\,\zeta\pars{3} + 31\zeta\pars{5} + 7\zeta\pars{3}\ln^{2}\pars{2} - {1 \over 8}\,\pi^{4}\ln\pars{2}}
\\[5mm] & \approx 0.0654
\end{align}